# np.add is giving me a headache. How do I use the where option in np.add?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays that are loaded from images, I need to add these two images, I.e. if there's a circle of pixel value 1 in the center, I need to add it with a triangle of pixel value 2 in the top left corner. The rule I want to set is that if the 1 is already in that index, it will only add pixel value 2 to the pixels that are blank (pixel value is 0)

How do I do that? I keep trying with np.add and the where option

```
mask_test = master_array == 0
master_array = np.add(master_array, new_pic, where = mask_test)
```

But it keeps screwing up and master_array just ends up being new_pic instead of the sum. Online searches of how 'where' works has been fruitless because everyone doesn't give an example, some even just go "oh it's not used much so I won't go over it".

This code:

```
master_array = np.add(master_array, new_pic, where = mask_test)
```

gives me this:

[image]

But the problem is when the pixels do overlap I get a pixel value of 3 instead of it retaining the value of 1 as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html), the `out` array will retain its "original value" in cases where the condition in the `where` parameter is false. This implies that you need to specify an `out` array to which the function will output if you are going to set the `where` parameter. Otherwise the function tries to get the original values from an uninitialized array, which has odd results. If you're happy to overwrite `master_array`, you can do that like this:

```
np.add(master_array, new_pic, out=master_array, where=master_array == 0)
```

(You don't need to assign the returned value here - specifying the output array is sufficient.)

It is probably less of a headache to use `+` with `np.where` instead:

```
master_array += np.where(master_array == 0, new_pic, 0)
```

But since you are only adding in cases where pixel value is 0 in the master, there is no need to add in the first place. You could just use `np.where` without any addition.

```
master_array = np.where(master_array == 0, new_pic, master_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of `where` in `np.add` (or other ufunc) is not common - especially compared to the use of the `np.where` function.  And at least when I answered SO, I stress the `out` needs to be included.

The docs talk about "uninitialized" values when `out=None`, the default.  That may be unclear, but effectively it means, an array such as that created by `np.empty`.

This may  contain anything, such as:

```
In [263]: res = np.empty((5,5),int)
In [264]: res
Out[264]: 
array([[            50999536,                    0,      140274438367024,
        -6315338160082163841,      140273540789184],
       [                 161,             55839504,      140274448227440,
             140273575343728,   358094631352936090],
       [     140273564120384,      140273575343344, -7783537013977118542,
             140273543024256,      140273575343200],
       [-6522034781934541837,      140273620247296,      140273575343776,
         1387433780369843801,      140273560270848],
       [     140273561761968, -3190833100527581043,      140273563628672,
             140273561762640,                  480]])
```

Define an initial array:

```
In [265]: x1 = np.random.randint(0,5,(5,5))
In [266]: x1
Out[266]: 
array([[3, 2, 0, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 4, 0, 3],
       [2, 3, 3, 4, 3],
       [3, 2, 0, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 1, 2]])
In [267]: x2=x1.copy()
```

Without `out`, we get values much like `res` above.  Only the `x1==0` elements are set to 10:

```
In [268]: np.add(x1, 10, where=x1==0)
Out[268]: 
array([[51108864,        0,       10, 47780512, 51193856],
       [51213024, 51245760, 51252528,       10, 51260336],
       [51261168, 51261920, 51264176, 51298864, 51270656],
       [51271040, 51274864,       10, 51276640, 51277024],
       [51277808, 51278528, 51279104, 51284496, 51286448]])
```

Or we could set the `out` to `np.zeros`:

```
In [269]: np.add(x1, 10, where=x1==0, out=np.zeros((5,5),int))
Out[269]: 
array([[ 0,  0, 10,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

But if we set it to `x1`, or a copy of `x1` (which is probably what you want):

```
In [270]: np.add(x1, 10, where=x1==0, out=x2)
Out[270]: 
array([[ 3,  2, 10,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  2,  4, 10,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  3,  4,  3],
       [ 3,  2, 10,  2,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  1,  1,  2]])
```

But we could do the same with masked addition:

```
In [271]: x1[x1==0] += 10
In [272]: x1
Out[272]: 
array([[ 3,  2, 10,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  2,  4, 10,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  3,  4,  3],
       [ 3,  2, 10,  2,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  1,  1,  2]])
```

Or using the more commonly use `np.where` function:

```
In [273]: np.where(x1==10, 20, x1)
Out[273]: 
array([[ 3,  2, 20,  1,  3],
       [ 3,  2,  4, 20,  3],
       [ 2,  3,  3,  4,  3],
       [ 3,  2, 20,  2,  2],
       [ 1,  2,  1,  1,  2]])
```

In my experience with SO, the `where/out` is most useful when evaluation at certain values can give rise to errors, for example division by 0, or log of negatives.

In  `np.where(A,B,C)`, the 3 arguments are evaluated in full, and result just selects from `B` and `C` based on `A`.  With the `np.add(x, y, where=A, out=C)`, the `x+y` addition is only done where the condition is true.  The evaluation is selective.  The distinction may be hard to grasp, and may not matter when using `np.add`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the normal addition:

```
mask_test = master_array == 0
master_array += new_pic * mask_test
```